# How to get value from row when its stored as an array in SQL

Tags: sql

```
pkid | columnValue
1     ('1', '11')
2     ('2', '11')
```

My table is called tbl.

I have this for a table and I need to be able to have a select statement that will only bring out the columnValue that has '1'. My problem is that I can't use LIKE and wildcard as it'll just bring out both rows.

When I do `WHERE columnValue = '1'` it doesnt return anything

Comment: @Stu wait sorry, that actually works! Do you want to write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data is delimited with quotes you can include those delimiters in your criteria by escaping them in the string:

```
where columnvalue like '%''1''%'
```